# Can I force my enable Container to redraw from a traitsui Handler?

Tags: python, enthought, traitsui, chaco

I have employed a `traitsui.api.Handler` to catch and handle events for a `traitsui.api.View`, that view includes a button, whose behavior is to remove a plot from a container containing multiple plots. The container's components list is accessed when the `remove` button is used, the `pop()` method is called, and the plot is removed. However, the view does not redraw, and so that plot appears to remain in place. Resizing with window through dragging a corner will force the redraw, confirming the `pop()`

The question is: How can I force the redraw programmatically ?

It seems to me that the right place to do so would be in the Handler's `setattr` method, just after `pop()`-ing the plot.

```
# Major library imports

from numpy import linspace
from scipy.special import jn

# Enthought library imports
from enable.api import Container, ComponentEditor
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, Button, Int, Str
from traitsui.api import Item, HGroup, View, VSplit, UItem, InstanceEditor, Handler

# Chaco imports
from chaco.api import ArrayPlotData, GridContainer, Plot

# ===============================================================================
# Attributes to use for the plot view.
size = (1000, 800)

COLOR_PALETTE = [
    (0.65098039, 0.80784314, 0.89019608, 1.0),
    (0.12156863, 0.47058824, 0.70588235, 1.0),
    (0.69803922, 0.8745098, 0.54117647, 1.0),
    (0.2, 0.62745098, 0.17254902, 1.0),
    (0.98431373, 0.60392157, 0.6, 1.0),
    (0.89019608, 0.10196078, 0.10980392, 1.0),
    (0.99215686, 0.74901961, 0.43529412, 1.0),
    (1., 0.49803922, 0., 1.0),
    (0.79215686, 0.69803922, 0.83921569, 1.0),
]


class InstanceUItem(UItem):
    """Convenience class for including an Instance in a View"""
    style = Str('custom')
    editor = Instance(InstanceEditor, ())



# ===============================================================================
# # ManagerHandler will be the View's handler
#===============================================================================
class ManagerHandler(Handler):
    def setattr(self, info, object, name, value):
        Handler.setattr(self, info, object, name, value)
        info.ui.context['pgrid'].plots_container.components.pop()
        #At this point, the container does not redraw, and so, while it no longer
        #contains the last plot in its components collection, that plot is still
        # visible

# ===============================================================================
# # PlotsGrid class that is used by the demo
#===============================================================================
class PlotsGrid(HasTraits):
    plots_container = Instance(Container)
    rows = Int(3)
    cols = Int(3)

    #===============================================================================
    # # Create the plots, this is adapted from the chaco GridContainer demo
    #===============================================================================
    def _plots_container_default(self):
        # Create a GridContainer to hold all of our plots
        container = GridContainer(padding=20, fill_padding=True,
                                  bgcolor="lightgray", use_backbuffer=True,
                                  shape=(self.rows, self.cols), spacing=(20, 20))

        # Create the initial series of data
        x = linspace(-5, 15.0, 100)
        pd = ArrayPlotData(index=x)

        # Plot some bessel functions and add the plots to our container
        for i in range(self.rows * self.cols):
            pd.set_data("y" + str(i), jn(i, x))
            plot = Plot(pd)
            plot.plot(("index", "y" + str(i)),
                      color=tuple(COLOR_PALETTE[i]), line_width=2.0,
                      bgcolor="white", border_visible=True)

            container.add(plot)
        return container



# ===============================================================================
# # Controls HasTraits provides a button used to wire in the desired behavior
#===============================================================================
class Controls(HasTraits):
    rem_plot = Button("remove ...")

    def _rem_plot_changed(self):
        print "rem plot changed"



# ===============================================================================
# # manager_view provides the View and defines its layout
#===============================================================================
manager_view = View(
    VSplit(
        HGroup(
            Item('controls.rem_plot', height=32)
        ),
        Item('pgrid.plots_container', editor=ComponentEditor(size=size), show_label=False),
        show_border=True
    ),
    handler=ManagerHandler(),
    resizable=True
)

grid = PlotsGrid()
ctrl = Controls()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ctrl.configure_traits(view=manager_view, context={'pgrid': grid, 'controls': ctrl})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to get this working is to call `invalidate_and_redraw` on your plot container after popping the plot. In that case, you could modify your call to `pop` to look something like:

```
plots_container = info.ui.context['pgrid'].plots_container
plots_container.components.pop()
plots_container.invalidate_and_redraw()
```

**Longer discussion:**

Ideally, this would be handled by Chaco. Part of the problem is that the container wasn't designed to have the `components` list modified directly. Instead, (I'm guessing) the intention was to have the user call `plots_container.remove` on an item in the `components` list.

That said, *that* doesn't seem to work either. It turns out that `remove` invalidates the current state, but doesn't request a redraw. (My guess is that chaco/enable doesn't automatically redraw since there may be many cache-invalidating operations in a row; e.g. if you were to remove all plots from this container, you'd only want to redraw after all the calls to `remove`, not after each one.)

So to actually use this alternative method, you would write something like:

```
plot = plots_container.components[-1]
plots_container.remove(plot)
plots_container.request_redraw()
```

Comment: Excellent. I'm happy to mark this out as the answer, it works like a charm. Do you mind if I ask where you're getting docs on this ? Enable is pretty low on documentation, so its a little bit of a slog figuring out the best means of working the API.

Comment: Unfortunately, my reply is based on experience and a quick look at the source code. Documentation is indeed a bit lacking here.